Intersections of Sets of Strings (Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas)
Consider the following four strings of text:


Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas


These strings of text represent four names for four different states within the United States of America.

Suppose that we are interested in writing code to implement a street address standardization tool.



INPUT
OUTPUT




AL
Alabama


Albma
Alabama


Alabama
Alabama


Alaska
Alaska


AK
Alaska


Alsk
Alaska




Question

What subsequences of the string of text Alabama are also sub-sequences of the string of text Alaska?


Suppose that $R$ is a function whose inputs are regular expressions and the outputs are sets of strings.
For example, $R(“\mathtt{A?l?a?}") = \{ “\mathtt{A}", “\mathtt{l}", “\mathtt{a}", “\mathtt{Al}", “\mathtt{Aa}", “\mathtt{la}", “\mathtt{Ala}" \} $

Please either write a regex, or create an explicit list, of all strings in the intersection described in the following mathematical notation.
$R(“\mathtt{A?l?a?b?a?m?a?}") \cap R(“\mathtt{A?l?a?s?k?a?}") $
